# How can I integrate an Asp.net page with a Python project?

Tags: c#, python, .net, machine-learning, python.net

I have a web page developed using Asp .Net MVC and I have a project developed in Python that has some methods to make predictions using Machine Learning. In this context, how can I make my web page communicate with my project in Python and use the methods implemented there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that your python file name is `script.py`, You can create a batch file that goes like this:

```
python C:\Users\script.py
```

And then call the batch file (script_runner.bat) from the ASP.NET program like this:

```
Process.Start('C:\Users.script_runner.bat');
```

Another possible solution is to use IronPython, [which works very good with ASP.NET](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/ironpython-for-asp-net-ctp).

Comment: Thanks Yuval, maybe use IronPython is the best way for what I'm thinking to do.